# How to embed a small camera preview, and then save the whole screenshot image in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, ios, camera

I want to put a background image first, and then put a small camera preview view on the top of it.

When user clicked the ok button, a screenshot of the whole merged picture could be reproduced. I remember that some apps in appstore did this, just want to know how to achieve this in code.

Answer (score 0):

Place your background image.. Over that place your imagepicker controller..

take screenshot using [UIGetScreenImage](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html)

Comment: I just thought the imagepicker controller takes full size of the whole screen. And it seems UIGetScreenImage has been disallowed to use.